# Aligning these items in thead

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to vertically align the column header the carets, but as you can see they are currently misaligned.

What I have so far (this is using bootstrap)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Table Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/all.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <table class="table table-dark table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">
              Title
              <div style="float: right; display: inline;">
                <div style="height: 16px">
                  <i class="fas fa-caret-up" style="height: fit-content; vertical-align: bottom; font-size: 20px;"></i>
                </div>
                <div style="height: 16px;">
                  <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="height: fit-content; vertical-align: top; font-size: 20px;"></i>
                </div>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">Foo</th>
            <th scope="col">Bar</th>
            <th scope="col">Quax</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

It produces this on my chrome:

[image]

The "Title" is too high and the carets are too low. How would I align them vertically in the middle of the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
th {
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
}

th .fas {
  position: absolute;
  right: 8px;
  line-height: 24px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-YWzhKL2whUzgiheMoBFwW8CKV4qpHQAEuvilg9FAn5VJUDwKZZxkJNuGM4XkWuk94WCrrwslk8yWNGmY1EduTA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<div class="container">
  <div>
    <table class="table table-dark table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">
            Title
            <i class="fas fa-sort"></i>
          </th>
          <th scope="col">Foo</th>
          <th scope="col">Bar</th>
          <th scope="col">Quax</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, fa-sort is neat! It does what I was trying to do manually.

Answer (score 0):

### You can try :

```css
th {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  text-align:center;
}
```

it should align your theads to the bottom center